has anyone ever seen this issue before where the wheel won't build after running pip install mysqlclient
enter image description here
I have tried a bunch of things too ix it but can't figure it out
any help would be appreciated thanks
I don't really know much about sql so any explanation about how the installation would work would also help
the wheel won't build

Note within the error: library 'zstd' not found, so whatever that is, likely needs to be installed.
